# Script to establish SSH tunnel and then run another program that uses the tunnel

Tags: ssh, scripts, postgresql

I am running a GUI app (Gnucash) that connects to a remote Postgres database via a secure shell session.  I can use the SSH -L command to tunnel a local port and then separately run Gnucash and this works fine.

What I'd like to do is use a single shell script that sets up the tunnel and then calls Gnucash.  Is that possible?  If so, how do I do it?
Currently, I run commands like the following in 2 separate terminal windows:

ssh -L 5433:127.0.0.1:19097 username@myserver.com.au
gnucash postgres://gnucash@localhost:5433/gnucash_db

If I simply put both lines in a shell script, the first line drops me into the remote shell and the second line doesn't execute until I exit the remote shell.

TIA,
Rob Hills

Comment: How about adding a `&` to the end of the first line?  Would that help?

Comment: I've not yet tried that, partly because I've been distracted by another task and partly because of the belief that using the & at the end would leave the tunnel process in the background, leaving the connection open.  Not sure if it would close when I finished the script or if it would stay open until I shut down Ubuntu.  I'll have to test this when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ssh -fNT -L 5433:127.0.0.1:19097 username@myserver.com.au` to ask ssh to automatically background after establishing the tunnel, and then your script can move on the next command. I suggest you end the script with an `exit`, which will close the terminal and kill the `ssh` process; otherwise you must either explicitly kill it or it will exit if/when the server times it out.

Comment: He wants to run gnucash on the remote server, so presumably he doesn't want -N.  Not sure how the -T interacts either, but the -f should do the trick.

Comment: No, Gnucash is running locally, using a remote postgres database.  The answer by izx works perfectly for me, many thanks.

Comment: This does *not* kill the ssh process, even with the explicit `exit` (which has no effect, since the script is would exit at the end of code anyway).